# Current measuring in a simple resistor and voltage circuit

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator

I have a problem with this simple circuit.

For LKC we know that the current on the node is

```
i1 = i2
```

since `i3` (the current going down is zero ).

In my ignorance I would measure `i1` like `i1 = V1/R1` and not like

```
i1 = (V1 - V2 - V3)/(R1 + R2)
```

It is clear that I cannot understand how this works.

[image]

Comment: V1 is not the voltage across R1, so you can't say i1 = V1/R1.

Comment: Can you please explain it to me better?

Comment: You should draw an arrow in the diagram indicating i1..i3.

Comment: Ignore the measurement point you've added. All you have is a series circuit, then. The voltages add (stack) so that you get +15 V + (-700 mV) + (-(-10 V))=24.3 V or else (-15 V + (700 mV) + (-10 V)=-24.3 V. (Just be consistent.) That's the sum of the voltage sources. Doesn't matter where they are in the series chain. They stack. Once you know that much, the current is had by dividing that voltage magnitude by the sum of the Rs.

Comment: Just because they're both labeled with the subscript '1' doesn't magically mean that V1 and R1 are in any way connected to each other. If you take that same circuit and label the left-most voltage source Vpq instead of V1 and label the left-most resistor R12 instead of R1, would you assume that i1 = Vpq/R12? I hope not ... In order to do a simple i=V/R calculation you need to know the Voltage *across* that Resistor, not some other arbitrary voltage in series with it.

Comment: This question will be closed if it is not edited to provide a better understanding of the question.

Comment: @jonk ok you hit the point; I don't understand why they stack and why we calculate the voltage across that resistor in that way. It is why we have to consider voltage between ground to ground? Thanks for be patient.

Comment: All circuitry is a _loop_! Get rid of the grounds and just tie those together instead. A ground is just a marker that gives you a "point of reference" when talking about voltages in a circuit. An actual circuit, built in isolation on a small board, doesn't know where the ground is and doesn't care. Using ground is for us humans, not for electrons or the universe around us which cares not the least bit about how we talk about the world.

Comment: Do not flag questions as low quality unless there is a serious problem (spam or blatant misuse). Edit the question if possilble Use the voting buttons if you don't like it. If there is a problem with the question then VTC.